# What is a phrase for constantly doing some or the other thing with an object?

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a word that means constantly doing something an object. I've heard the word 'mendel' 'mendeling' used in context with gadgets but I seem to find no information about it.

For ex. *Jack can be seen constantly **mendeling** with circuits*

I'm not sure if that's the exact spelling.

Comment: You're probably thinking of "meddling" but "fiddling" is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @KillingTime - "Mendeling" would be appropriate if he were studying their genetics.

Comment: @VanditGoel Can you please mark this question as complete, since it solved your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> You're probably thinking of "meddling" but "fiddling" is a better fit.

KillingTime

Answer (score 0):

Here's one, from [the jargon file](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://vanderworp.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/jargon.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwihtOSm97boAhWrKLkGHcSSDGsQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw2GB0_T3qmz0V_HvUquxgRt), primarily a collection of hacker lore:.

> **frobnicate** /frob'ni-kayt/ vt. (Poss. derived from frobnitz, and usually abbreviated to frob, but 'frobnicate' is recognized as the official full form.) To manipulate or adjust, to tweak. One frequently frobs bits or other 2-state devices. Thus:  "Please frob the light switch" (that is, flip it), but also "Stop frobbing that clasp; you'll break it". One also  sees the construction `to frob a frob'. See **tweak** and **twiddle**.